# Runtime: no suchfile or directory

Tags: python, netcdf

I am getting the following error when I run my python script:

```
/Documents/stage/crocus/python$ python bonaiguaforcing.py
sh: 1: ncks: not found
sh: 1: ncatted: not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bonaiguaforcing.py", line 142, in <module>
    creatforc('/home/chomette/Documents/stage/crocus/bonaigua2.txt','/home/chomette/Documents/stage/crocus/FORCING_bonaigua.nc')
  File "bonaiguaforcing.py", line 46, in creatforc
    meteo=netCDF4.Dataset(net_out,'a')
  File "netCDF4/_netCDF4.pyx", line 1746, in netCDF4._netCDF4.Dataset.__init__ (netCDF4/_netCDF4.c:10983)
RuntimeError: No such file or directory
```

In my python script I create a netCDF file to copy data and then I create a new netCDF file with a new variable, it seems that python didn't find the first netCDF file created.... but I'm not sure.
Thanks for your help =)

Comment: Can you post your script or at least the part you think is raising the error?

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the code producing the error, this looks like an environment definition problem. Your shell can't find where NCO is installed (if you don't have NCO then this is a dependency problem and you need to install it for your script to work).

Have you tried in bash :

```
  which ncks
  which ncatted
```

If these are not in your path, you are going to need to add aliases pointing to them in your bash rc, execute under your home directory the following (with vi or another editor) :

```
vi .bashrc
```

then add to the file:

```
alias ncks='/usr/bin/ncks'
alias ncatted='/usr/bin/ncatted'
```

You will need to change `/usr/` to the location of your NCO installation. Also, don't forget to source `. .bashrc` before testing your program again. You can also just type your aliases into the shell, but you will need to do this each time you open a new terminal.

Updated answer (based on your comment below): 
now it appears that your script is not finding part of the `netCDF4` module (the part of it written in c, hence the .pyx extension). You'll need to make sure that your environment is correctly defined and that the netCDF module has been correctly compiled. Before going any farther, type the following commands in a terminal:

```
python
from netCDF4 import Dataset
```

to make sure that the module exists. If that works, then you can follow the instructions on https://netcdf4-python.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/netCDF4-module.html to create a dataset in order to make sure that the module was correctly compiled.

For information, are your porting the crocus model to a new machine ? If so, that might explain why you are missing so many dependencies (modules, libraries and operators that your code needs in order to function). If not, there may be another error in your script which is making this look like a dependency problem. Please post part of your script for generating the crocus forcings if you do not think this is a problem with your environment/dependencies (ie if someone has already run the same script on your machine and it worked). Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for you answer, do you know an aswer website to install the modul Dataset? cause this one https://netcdf4-python.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/netCDF4-module.html does not function.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, i have now my simulation with crocus, but when i want to plot, i have (an other time) the probleme with  :   cro_pro = netCDF4.Dataset("PRO_2015090106_2016043006_dust.nc",'r')
  File "netCDF4/_netCDF4.pyx", line 1746, in netCDF4._netCDF4.Dataset.__init__ (netCDF4/_netCDF4.c:10983)
RuntimeError: No such file or directory.  
I think my machin doesn't find the Dataset Modul, but i had install the package "python interface for netcdf4", how can i know if the modul Dataset modul is installed?

Comment: To find out if the Dataset class has been installed, just create a python script with only `from netCDF4 import Dataset` inside. If it runs, then you have properly installed the netCDF4 module for python and the error is elsewhere. You can find all the software that must be installed for for the netCDF4 python API here: http://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/#netCDF4.Dataset. Please note that you must run your plotting software in the same directory as your netCDF file if you do not provide a path with the file name (ie netCDF4.Dataset("/path/myfile.nc", 'r')).

Answer (score 0):

You're seeing a `RuntimeError` because the filename specified in `netout` does not exist--the `'a'` mode (append) requires that the file exist.